# PHP error when using Low Variables 2.4.0

Tags: ee2, low-variables

Has anyone come across this error with Low Variables?

Trying to create a new variable (the first one for this install):

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1364

Field 'variable_data' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `exp_global_variables` (`variable_name`, `site_id`) VALUES ('lv_test', '1')

Filename: third_party/low_variables/mcp.low_variables.php

Line Number: 1135
```

This was trying to get create a textarea filed. Get the same error when trying to create an Assets field too:

```
Error Number: 1364

Field 'variable_data' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `exp_global_variables` (`variable_name`, `site_id`) VALUES ('lv_assets', '1')

Filename: third_party/low_variables/mcp.low_variables.php

Line Number: 1135
```

EE 2.7.2
LV 2.4.0

Comment: It's a known issue in some MySQL environments. Email me at hi at gotolow dot com for a patch. (Making this an official answer, too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue in LV 2.4.0 with some MySQL environments. Email me at hi at gotolow dot com for a patch. It will be fixed in 2.4.1.